# opening utf8 files on perl and double encoding

Tags: perl, utf-8

I have mysql db which have COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' for every table.

i connect to the tables with dbi **`my $db = DBI->connect($cstring, $user, $password)`** and  without

```
$db->{mysql_enable_utf8} = 1
$db->do(qq{SET NAMES 'utf8';} );
```

Then select the table and copy it to the csv file using Text::CSV to myFile where myFile is opened like the the below :

```
binmode(Myfile, ":utf8")
```

The problem that i repeat this process on different tables with different files which opened like the above but on some files i get double encoding and only if i remove the binmode for those speicfic files the problem is solved while the other files are fine and encoded utf8  and if i remove the binmode for them i get a problem on the utf8 encdoing what could be the problem ?

worth to mention i tried to use : **use utf8** on my script and also tried to use

```
 $db-> {mysql_enable_utf8} = 1
    $db->do(qq{SET NAMES 'utf8';} );
```

but the problem is not solved.

Comment: When you configure the files with binmode `:utf8`, you need to make sure the strings you feed it are `utf8::is_utf8`, because if they are not, they will be decoded from iso-8859-1 and encoded in utf8 resulting in double-encoding. You either have to configure the connection to return the strings properly marked as utf-8 or `utf8::decode` them yourself.

Comment: Or you can do without the binmode; it should not modify the encoding then.

Comment: Are you certain that the problem isn't that some of the database tables contain double-encoded values? (i.e. the problem you describe can happen on either input or output.)

Comment: how can i make sue the string i feed is utf8::is_utf8 while configuring the binmode thanks

Comment: Never use `is_utf8`. Never. It is a debugging tool only. What Jan Hudec said is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have access to `phpMyAdmin`? Can check if the database contents are correct using `phpMyAdmin`? Either you omitted something or your database contents are wrong.

Comment: this a problematic charachter Â  from the phpMyAdmin

Comment: So the problem is that your database contents are wrong (double-encoded).

Comment: how can i correct my database content to utf8 as my table are :COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'

Comment: It has nothing to do will your database settings. It's because the wrong data was put into the database.

Comment: is there an option to corret all the table data with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you see

```
Ã©Ã«Ã¨
```

where you expect

```
éëè
```

when using phpMyAdmin. This indicates the data in your database is wrong (double-encoded). You'll need to go back and repopulate your database with the correct data.

---

If you can't fix your database, it's most likely safe to just add the following:

```
utf8::decode($str);  # Fix double-encoding
```

It will attempt to decode the already-decoded data from the database. If the data was double-encoded, this will fix it. If the data wasn't double-encoded, it will fail silently fail, leaving the correct value in `$str` (assuming your strings aren't very very weird).

I recommend that you write a small tool that reads the data from the database, uses this trick to fix the data, then puts it back in the database correctly.

Comment: Thanks to the answer it helped me a lot just another question if i need to populate my data again using DBI and the data are utf8 itself how should i configure the dbi ?