# Multiple XLSX files to multiple CSV files using perl

Tags: perl

I have the below script which is converting xlsx to csv but if the cell value has comma (,) in between, it is moving to next column in csv which is wrong. Colud you please correct it? Also, how can convert multiple xlsx files to mulptiple csv files in one go?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use Text::CSV qw(csv);

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('/path/file.xlsx');
my $csv = '/path/File.csv';
open(my $FH ,'>',"$csv") or die "failed to open";

my $line;
foreach my $sheet (@{$excel -> {Worksheet}}) {
    printf("Sheet: %s\n", $sheet->{Name});
    $sheet -> {MaxRow} ||= $sheet -> {MinRow};
    foreach my $row ($sheet -> {MinRow} .. $sheet -> {MaxRow}) {
        $sheet -> {MaxCol} ||= $sheet -> {MinCol};
        foreach my $col ($sheet -> {MinCol} ..  $sheet -> {MaxCol}) {
            my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [$row] [$col];
            #if ($cell) {
            #    $line .= "\"".$cell -> {Val}."\",";
                        #       $line .= $cell -> {Val};
                        #       if ($col != $sheet -> {MaxCol}) #appends the comma only if the column being processed is not the last
                        #       {
                        #               $line .= ",";
                        #       }
            #}
                        if (defined $cell && defined $cell->Value) {
               if ($col != $sheet -> {MaxCol})
               {
               print $FH $cell->Value.",";
              }
            else
             {
            print $FH $cell->Value ;
             }
          } else {
            if ($col != $sheet -> {MaxCol})
               { print $FH ",";
               }
             }

        }
$FH =~ s/,$//; # replace comma at the end of the string with empt
       print $FH "\n";
      }
```

Comment: still it is going to next column. Is there any other way to restrict the field with comma(,) in between to one field after conversion from xlsx to csv?

Comment: check for the cell value contain ',' if ',' present add double quotes.  write method and pass $cell->value to check string contain ','   `sub check_cell_string {
    my ($string) = @_;
    my $substr = ',';
    if (index($string, $substr) != -1) { $string = '"'.$string.'"';}
    return $string;
}`  and before print $FH statement call this method `my $str = check_cell_string($cell->value) ; print $FH $str.",";  OR print $FH $str;`

Comment: for example in csv file entry look like this `1, 1928,44,Emil Jannings,"The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh"`

Comment: @briandfoy I have explained here .. I have deleted the script

Comment: @amit Your comment as it is could be an answer. If you have a lot of code in a comment, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Brian, how can we master in perl..? Any tips, please?

Comment: @briandfoy as per your suggestion, I have added the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @johnroberto - I have many books that will help you master Perl. One's even called [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org).

Comment: Thank you, Brian...Looks like you are a Big Guy..!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Check for the cell value contain ',' char. if ',' char present in
> sting add double quotes to string. Write a method and pass
> $cell->value to check string contain char ','.

for example

```
sub check_cell_string {     
    my ($string) = @_;     
    my $substr = ',';     
    if (index($string, $substr) != -1) { 
        $string = '"'.$string.'"';
    }     
    return $string; 
}
```

and then call file write statement.

```
my $str = check_cell_string($cell->value);
print $FH $str;
```

for example, in the csv file entry look like below

```
1, 1928,44,Emil Jannings,"The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh"
```

Comment: Amit, another question for converting xlsx data to csv.                                                            In xlsx file, the data is like : Bob & Mathew                                                                       but after conversion , the data in csv file is like: Bob &amp: Mathew.                                 How to handle this? any idea?

Comment: If you don't decode UTF-8 text/octets, Perl will assume they are encoded with N8CS (often ISO-8859-1/Latin-1). This means that the individual octets of a multi-byte UTF-8 character are seen as separate characters (not good). If these separate characters are later encoded to UTF-8 for output, a "double encoding" results. This is similar to HTML double encoding — e.g., &amp;gt; instead of &gt;.

Comment: I am not aware of your current code but check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292229/opening-utf8-files-on-perl-and-double-encoding   `utf8::decode($str);  # Fix double-encoding` before writing to file  decode string  and  url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096900/how-do-i-avoid-double-utf-8-encoding-in-xmllibxml

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the multiple files question, you should be able to do something like this:

```
my @csv = ('/path/File.csv', 'secondfile', 'thirdfile');

foreach (@csv)
{
    my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ($_.".xslx");
    ...
}
```